# Ostwald gas solubility for air-sea gas exchange of O2

Tags: air, oceanography

The bubble-mediated component of the air-sea gas exchange can be parameterized with Woolf's (1997) formula as:

$$ K_{b} = W \frac{2450}{\beta_{0} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{\left( 14\beta_{0}Sc^{-0.5}\right)^{1/1.2}} \right)^{1.2} }$$

I can calculate $W$ following Equation 1.8 in [this paper by Soloviev *et al* 2007](http://www.nova.edu/ocean/Physics/PDF/Solovievetal2007.pdf) (NB: PDF),
but I'm struggling to find the equation to calculate $\beta_{0}$, the [Ostwald gas solubility](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=Ostwald%20gas%20solubility). Given that this equation is used to calculate the flux of O2, does anyone know the value to use for $\beta_{0}$ as they do not specify in the link provided.

Comment: Is $\beta_0$ you want for air or seawater?

Comment: its for the air

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emerson & Hedges' *Chemical Oceanography and the Marine Carbon Cycle* ([Google book link](http://books.google.com/books?id=BwRSn2ikJW4C&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=ostwald+gas+solubility+of+air&source=bl&ots=xEAz2eGsmf&sig=XwsK-GsEomEdnDIa_HR8FPV12iA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UUhaVIqhCcGiNpSeg9gC&ved=0CCgQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=ostwald%20gas%20solubility%20of%20air&f=false), you'll have to scroll to page 87) has a table that gives the value $\beta_0=2.71\times10^{-2}$ for air in seawater at 20$^\circ$C and one atmosphere.

[This website](http://oxygen.atomistry.com/solubility_oxygen.html) has a table of values at multiple temperatures from a few different published sources--the value at 20$^\circ$C is slightly higher than the above source at $\beta=3.12\times10^{-2}$. It also includes a formula that fits the empirical data:
$$
\beta(T)=0.04890 – 0.0013413T + 0.0000283T^2 - 0.00000029534T^3.
$$
(Their terminology on this latter page seems a bit different, as they seem to call both $\beta$ and $I$ as the solubility, with the relation $I=\beta(1+ 0.00367T)$ that appears to be small enough to make them effect equivalent, maybe?)